# livewire on rerender can't access the request value, until next browser refresh

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

My problem is, when i make a very simple pagination with Laravel Livewire, the first page appear just fine, but when i click "Next Page/Page Number", the result just disappear, even though there are still more results to show, i'm absolutely got no idea, no mattter how i try.
the same problem when i try delete one category

Here is my Component code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin\Category;
use App\Models\Categories;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Index extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';
    public $category_id;
    public function deleteCategory($category_id){
        $this->category_id=$category_id;
    }
    public function render(Request $request)
    {
        $categories = Categories::orderBy('id','ASC')->paginate(1);
        return view('livewire.admin.category.index',['categories'=>$categories]);
    }

    public function destroyCategory(){
        $category = Categories::find($this->category_id);
        $old_image_patch = 'admins/images/categories/';
        if (file_exists($old_image_patch.$category->image)){
            unlink($old_image_patch.$category->image);
        }
        $category->delete();
        session()->flash('message','xoa thanh cong');
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('close-modal');

    }

}
```

I have already include the livewire @livewireStyles and @livewireScripts, and i can't find an answer anywhere else cause i don't see any question that match my problem, and i'm kinda new to livewire

Comment: Hi Linh, could you also post the view you are using to show your results? I think we can help you better when we have a complete picture.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your view file has a base `div` tag.

```php
<div>
    // All the other view code here
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think you can answer this question before you have seen the corresponding view this person is using do you?

Comment: I couldn't put the suggestion as a comment due to not being at 50, therefore had to post it as an answer. Which seems a bit backwards. Can't ask clarifying question but can post answers. Just trying to be helpful.

However, to directly answer your question, I have seen the issue as the OP posted and it was due to the missing div's. May not be the solution here and may be the solution.